# How to select specific files according to a spreadsheet criteria and then copy from directory to another directory in R?

Tags: r

I have a task that requires me to use a specific column in a CSV spreadsheet that stores the file names, for example:

| File Name |
| --- |
| CA-001 |
| WV-001 |
| ma-001 |

My task is to move some files from folder 'source' to folder 'target'.

And I'm using this csv spreadsheet as a crosswalk to select any files with names that match with what's in the column 'File Name'. Then I'm asking R to copy from the source folder that contains not only these files but also other files that are not in this list(eg: CO-001, SC-001...). If it's helpful, all of the files are PDFs, so we don't worry about file type. I want only the files that have names match with what's in the csv spreadsheet. How can I do this?

I have some sample code below, but it still didn't execute successfully.

```
source <- "C:/Users/53038/MovePDF/Test_From"
target <- "C:/Users/53038/MovePDF/Test_To"

all.files <- list.files(path = source)

csvfile <- read.csv('C:/Users/53038/MovePDF/Master.csv')

toCopy <- all.files[all.files %in% csvfile$Move]

file.copy(toCopy, target)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here as but in `list.files()` there is a `pattern` argument. You can feed your vector of source files separated by `|` (kind of like you would a regex), and that should pull all of your desired files.

Comment: Your `paste0()` is not used to paste anything, is this normal ?

Comment: Thanks! I rewrote my code above and hope it's more clear

Comment: Creating a big regex pattern would work, but it would be extremely slow for long lists of files and/or large directories. And you'd have to excape any special characters.

Comment: Do you want files with an *identical* match (or possibly with ".pdf" appended to it), or any file containing the strings in your csv?

Comment: @CasparV. I want the files with identical match to what's in the csv. All the files are PDFs. So I don't know if it's easier to clean up my csv to have no ".pdf" or if it's easier to remove ".pdf" from the list of file names.

Answer (score 0):

With the provided code, the selection of patterns you want to match will be in `csvfile$File.Name`.

I'm assuming the source directory is potentially very large. Instead of performing slow regular expressions to match substrings (while we know the exact filename), and/or getting a complete file listing (which is also slow), I will only seek if the exactly wanted filenames exist before copying them:

```
source <- "C:/Users/53038/MovePDF/Test_From"
target <- "C:/Users/53038/MovePDF/Test_To"

csvfile <- read.csv('C:/Users/53038/MovePDF/Master.csv')
    
# add .pdf suffix
toCopy <- paste0(csvfile$File.Name,'.pdf')

# add source directory path
toCopy <- file.path(source,  toCopy)

# optional: extract only the existing files from toCopy. You can skip this step if you're sure they exist and/or you don't mind receiving errors
toCopy <- toCopy[file.exists(toCopy)]

# make it so
file.copy(toCopy, target, overwrite = T)
```

I would preferably keep the `.pdf` extension in the filename at all times, so also in the source CSV. There would be an issue on case-sensitive filesystems (almost all Linux installations, rarely macOS or Windows) if the extension is .PDF, .Pdf, etc.